Show that a sinusoidal is an eigenfunction of an LTI system
I'm having trouble writing the math behind the phenomenon of the response of a linear, time-invariant (LTI) system for a sinusoidal input. I know from working with circuits and their ac analysis that given a LTI system, if the input is a sinusoidal signal the output will be a scaled and shifted sinusoidal of the same frequency (it seems, experimentally, that the sine wave is an eigenfunction of the system). But when I trying to prove this I get stuck in the following reasoning:
Let $x(t)=A\sin(2\pi f_0t)$ be the input and $\mathcal{H}$ be the transformation corresponding to an LTI system. So $y(t)=\mathcal{H}[x(t)]$ is the output. Knowing that complex exponentials are the eigenfunctions of $\mathcal{H}$ and $H(f_0)$, its frequency response, is the eigenvalue of $\mathcal{H}$, then I write $$x(t)=A\frac{e^{j2\pi f_0t}-e^{-j2\pi f_0t}}{2j}.$$
Implying that, $\because\;\mathcal{H}[e^{j2\pi f_0 t}]=H(f_0)e^{j2\pi f_0 t},$ $$y(t)=\frac{A}{2j}\left[H(f_0)e^{j2\pi f_0t}-H(-f_0)e^{-j2\pi f_0t}\right].$$
And I cannot further simplify this expression, to have something like $H(f_0)\sin(2\pi f_0t)$ to show that it's scaled and shifted by the magnitude and phase of $H$, because $H$ is not generally even or odd. Can someone bring to light what's wrong with my reasoning?

Is this a homework question or just curious?

@Baddioes I came across it analyzing the response of a bandpass filter to an input triangular wave for a report

Everything you did is correct. The problem is that you can't prove that sinusoids are eigenfunctions of LTI system because they aren't.
What you mean is that if the input signal to a real-valued LTI system with frequency response $H(j\omega)$ has the form $x(t)=\sin(\omega_0t)$, then its output is given by
$$y(t)=|H(j\omega_0)|\sin\big(\omega_0t+\arg\big\{H(j\omega_0)\big\}\big)\tag{1}$$
Note that if sinusoids were eigenfunctions of LTI systems, the output should be given by
$$y(t)=\lambda(\omega_0)\sin(\omega_0t)$$
with some eigenvalue $\lambda(\omega_0)$.
Eq. $(1)$ can be shown exactly as you did and noting that for real-valued LTI systems we have $H(-j\omega)=H^*(j\omega)$, where $^*$ denotes complex conjugation. Then you get
$$y(t)=\frac{1}{2j}\big[H(j\omega_0)e^{j\omega_0t}-\left(H(j\omega_0)e^{j\omega_0t}\right)^*\big]=\textrm{Im}\left\{H(j\omega_0)e^{j\omega_0t}\right\}$$
which equals $(1)$.
